# DigitalPersona SDK Runtime issues with Windows 10 IoT Enterprise

Tags: windows, digital-persona-sdk, windows-10-iot-enterprise

I hope someone can help me.
We recently purchased a new kiosk model that has a built-in computer. The OS installed on this computer is Windows 10 IoT Enterprise.
These kiosks are also equipped with a DigitalPersona fingerprint scanner (U.are.U 4500) and we usually install this driver: DigitalPersona SDK Runtime 3.4.0.127.

We use a web-based software on these kiosks (using Chrome) and this is what we received from the vendor:

Our primary concern is whether the SDK on the kiosk is being loaded and allowed. When we look at the logs the entire payload for the scan (MimeType-Image/Png) is absent which means the scan of the fingerprint is not being sent to the software. Possible scenarios might include:

- SDK not being loaded in the browser session on the kiosk
- Use of that peripheral being disallowed by the OS
- The URL requesting the scan being disallowed/blocked by the kiosk

Do you have any suggestions on what I can check?

The old kiosk model was using Windows 10 Professional so there is definitely something different in the new OS.

Thank you
Marco

We haven't tried too much because the knowledge of Win 10 IoT Enterprise is not so high.